# LightningChart -- real-time data monitor

Tags: javascript, animation, real-time-data, lightningchart

I am trying to create a (near) real-time data monitor using LightningChart.
The data is pushed every 3 seconds and 6 seconds worth of data is pushed every time.
So I tried using this example to create a steady animation: [Progressive xAxis - Timed Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842825/progressive-xaxis-timed-interval)
but the timing doesn't seem quite right.
It needs to animating exactly at 500 points per second.

Eventually it needs to have multiple different data streams /charts that have a different number of points per second (500, 70, 50).

I think I am trying to make some combination of the above stackoverflow post and one of the LightningChart examples, e.g. https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0029-htmlScrollDashboard.html?isList=false

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
I am happy to provide more information or clarification if the above it not helpful enough.

Thank you so much in advance!
T

Tried combinations of the stackoverflow post, getanimation frame, tried manipulating the lightningchart examples, all with no success

Comment: or maybe similar to this https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-0013-timeTickStrategyScrolling.html?isList=false  which has a timed X-axis

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes that is the sort of thing!   I was also trying to work out if it is possible to scroll along the x-axis (i.e. not zoom in/out but move along in time).  Any chance this possible in LightningChart?